# programing language and training environment for machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, game-engine, game-development, reinforcement-learning

I need advice on which libraries and game engines should I use for a ml project

my goal is to create machine learning model for pruning the trees. I believe I have to create a game with generic tree model with some randomness then create reinforcement learning model and train ml model inside the game.ML model must have ability to first find the branch which must be cut and then find a path to move robotic arm near to that branch to cut it. I have experience in c++ and java but I prefer c++ , could you give me advise which library should I use for ML and which language and game engine should I use for creating game? I have a little experience in opengl. If it doesn't make any difference my prefered language is c++ but I know that I should use right tool for right job and python is leader in ML so if it will save a time and energy I have nothing against learning python.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to learn and use Python for your ML project. Though there is some work in R, for your future in ML, your best bet is to learn and use Python. The community is great, and there are many frameworks that can work out-of-the-box.

After a quick search, I did find a framework called `robotframework`, that is pretty highly starred on GitHub here: https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework. I will say though, however, that I am not personally familiar with using this framework. But it may be helpful to you.

In terms of tree-based algorithms, you might want to start exploring with XGBoost. It can be found here: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost.